# Adding A Trailing Backslash Cause A Error 500

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Adding a trailing backslash to the end of the URL causes a Error 500, i.e /forum/. When entered /forum, /forum.php is loaded onto browser as intended. Upon checking the error log file, it states

> Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable
>   configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the
>   limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(admin|user)($|/) - [L]


#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)$ /index.php?view=$1 [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?view=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

If I add a backslash '?/', /forum would load the index page and /forum/ would load /forum.php

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)?/$ $1.php [L]
```

Where did I go wrong? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

This `RewriteCond` condition should prevent rewriting in case the requested file exists. In your case, `/forum` will be rewritten to `/forum.php`, then the rewritten request is handed back to the URL parsing engine which will find that `/forum.php` exists and this rule will not be execited again.

When you request `/forum/`, it is rewritten to `/forum/.php` which does not exist so it is rewritten to `/forum/.php.php` etc. You can se this in error log if you enable Rewrite [logging](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging)

The quick fix would be to strip trailin slash with this (put it below `RewriteBase /`:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [NC,L]
```